# Converting char to unsigned integer

Tags: c++

I read a huge binary file into a vector of `char`s.

I need to treat every byte as an unsigned integer(from 0 to 255); and do some arithmetics. How can I convert vector to vector?

---

```
char a = 227;
cout << a;
```

prints ?

---

```
char a = 227;
int b = (int) a;
cout << b << endl;
```

prints -29

---

```
char a = 227;
unsigned int b = (unsigned int) a;
cout << b << endl;
```

prints 4294967267

---

```
char a = 227;
unsigned char b = (unsigned char) a;
cout << b << endl;
```

prints ?

Comment: I already have that vector<char>. when I convert `char` to `unsigned char` it still prints ?

Comment: char -> unsigned char -> int/unsigned

Comment: @Kevin yes it does the trick. Is there an easy way of converting the vector<char> to vector<unsigned char> in one step?

Comment: You should be able to use the constructor taking 2 iterators (`std::vector<unsigned char> uchars(chars.begin(), chars.end());`) If you already constructed the 2nd vector you can use `clear` and `insert`. Printing this will still have the same issue.

Comment: What about instead of unsigned int, you make it a byte?  Does that give you what you want?  A byte has a valid range of 0 to 255.

Comment: @Russ - byte is not a standard type in C or C++.

Comment: Seems like you're using the wrong data structure. Using `vector<unsigned char>` instead of `vector<char>` will eliminate the signedness issues without having to convert any data.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<char> source;
// ... read values into source ...

// Make a copy of source with the chars converted to unsigned chars.
std::vector<unsigned char> destination;
for (const auto s : source) {
  destination.push_back(static_cast<unsigned char>(s))
}

// Examine the values in the new vector.  We cast them to int to get
// the output stream to format it as a number rather than a character.
for (const auto d : destination) {
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(d) << std::endl;
}
```